# C# PrincipalServerdownException even when I'm a real user

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, active-directory

I have an account in a domain.

When I try to connect to it with the following code, I get an exception
    PrincipalServerdownException

Here is the offending code

```
Console.WriteLine("User Name: " + userName + " Password: " + tb.Text.ToString().Trim());
System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext pc = new System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "COURTS.JUDICIARY.STATE.NJ.US");
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm stating the obvious, but make sure your domain is in fact available. The exception you're getting clearly states the the `COURTS.JUDICIARY.STATE.NJ.US` domain is offline.